# Point lights not lighting at all; at wits end!

Tags: rendering, modifiers, light

Fairly new to Blender here, quite excited about its capabilities, but unhappy with its quirkiness and unpredictability (to a newbie).

I have been making a tunnel to get some practice with the array and curve modifiers.

Initially, I modeled the road pavement, two sidewalks and the tunnel wall, using an array modifier followed by a curve modifier; I then edited the shape of the path curve to give the entire tunnel some non linearity.

Subsequently, I added a point light to the left side of the tunnel wall, and made it follow the path of the curve used with the tunnel, so that I had one light every few meters.These worked correctly, illuminating the scene as expected.

To model the light bulbs, I added an ico sphere near the first light, similarly made to follow the path of the curve of the tunnel, and coincide with the location of the point lights.

At that point, and as I was moving the point lights back and forth, to make sure they appear near but not inside the ico spheres, I realized that everything was rendering to complete black, none of the lights showing anymore!

I tried adding a sun outside the tunnel, and found out that it lighted the mouth of the tunnel correctly. I even moved the point lights to the center of the tunnel, to no avail. None of the lights inside the tunnel provide light anymore!

I checked the normals, they remain correctly flipped so that they point inside the tunnel.

I am literally at wits end, and look forward to some help.

[image]

Comment: ... ok the previous comment was false (deleted now). The curve itself is dupliframe and this is the reason. Set the dupli to "none" for the curve.

Comment: And a side note, not completely related to your question. Since you work in Cycles, you shouldn't need both lamps *and* emissive meshes in the same location. Unlike Blender Internal, emissive materials in Cycles don't just shine, but *do* light up the surroundings as well.

Comment: @lemon thank you being spot on! It took me a few (newbie) minutes to understand your comment on the duplicated curve, and you are right! I had, somehow, inadvertently turned on duplication for the curve as well! Not sure why that killed the lights, but my problem is solved, and I thank you very much indeed.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley thank you very much for you suggestion on lamps & emissive materials! I had done some experiments and suspected as much, but was not sure.

Comment: To further this, the strength for the emission shader on a mesh is given in watts per square metre. Your sphere has a visible surface area of approximately 0.1 sq.m, so to get 100W, you'd need to set the strength to 1000 (=100/0.1).

Comment: @JohnParavantis, the "why": if dupliframe is used, then you need a parent object to duplicate it on. If there is nothing as parent, the duplicate is not generated... so nothing appears

Comment: Thank you very much @lemon! Since I have your attention, I would like to ask a related question (to avail of your expertise): the curve modifier used after an array modifier, appears to work well along the X axis but it goes bonkers if used along the Y direction, e.g. the dimensions of the object extended as an array along the curve are all over the place and cannot be corrected by typing in new values at the transform pane (even when resetting for scale and rotation after every change). Are there any known such problems/issues/bugs?

Comment: Wow @DuaneDibbley, thank you! Great to know!

Comment: @JohnParavantis, it is globally dependent on both arrayed object and curve global orientations. Hard to explain/develop more in the comments...

Comment: If anything else, this: When you parent an object to a curve and dupliframe it, the dimensions of the objects are reported as the "correct" dimensions of the original (single) object; this way, it is easy to make any changes. If, on the other hand, an object is duplicated via an array modifier and made to follow a curve by a curve modifier, the dimensions of the object apparently refer to the entire array, so it is difficult to change them in a meaningful fashion. This appears to be more of a problem when the curve modifier is directed towards the Y axis. My two pennies anyway.